# Trying to prove map is a ${\mathbb Z}$-module isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is a follow-on question from my earlier question [Trying to prove structure result for ${\rm Hom}(A,B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468282/trying-to-prove-structure-result-for-rm-homa-b) about isomorphic $A$-modules.

Thinking about this a bit more and people's comments on that question, I realise that although it is very easy to see the modules are isomorphic as ${\mathbb Z}$-modules, I cannot see how to prove in general that the map I gave there is a ${\mathbb Z}$-module isomorphism (rather than an $A$-module isomorphism as requested in the original question).

Here is the situation again and my new question here.

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb Z$-algebra that is finitely-generated and free as a $\mathbb Z$-module and let $\pi: A \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ a nontrivial $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism.

Let $m$ be a positive integer and consider the ${\mathbb Z}$-module homomorphism from $A/mA$ to ${\rm Hom}_{\,\mathbb Z}(A/mA, \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ defined by mapping $\overline{a}$ (the coset of $a \in A$ in $A/mA$) to the homomorphism defined by taking $\overline{b}$ to $\pi(ab) \bmod m$ (where $ab$ is the product of $a$ and $b$ in $A$).

Under suitable conditions (e.g., $m$ relatively prime to some integer depending on $A$ and $\pi$, probably), it seems that the above ${\mathbb Z}$-module homomorphism from $A/mA$ to ${\rm Hom}_{\,\mathbb Z}(A/mA, \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ is actually a ${\mathbb Z}$-module isomorphism. But I cannot see how to prove this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.